# SharpAvi Image to ByteArray to Frame to AVI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, video, bitmap, arrays

I'm having some trouble converting an image to a video using the SharpAVI.dll.

I have managed to produce a video file using a randomly generated byte array by using the documentation on SharpAVI's website:

[Getting Started with SharpAVI](https://sharpavi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Documentation)

So the next step I thought I would take was to take an Image, create a Bitmap image, convert the bitmap to a byte array and then simply save the byte array to each frame of the video file. When I run the program, I get no errors or anything and a video file of an appropriate file size is produced however the video file is unreadable and will not open. I'm really struggling to see why this won't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Code:

```
private void GenerateSingleImageVideo()
    { 
        string imagePath = textBoxImagePath.Text;
        Bitmap thisBitmap;

        //generate bitmap from image file
        using (Stream BitmapStream = System.IO.File.Open(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Image img = Image.FromStream(BitmapStream);
            thisBitmap = new Bitmap(img);
        }

        //convert the bitmap to a byte array
        byte[] byteArray = BitmapToByteArray(thisBitmap);

        //creates the writer of the file (to save the video)
        var writer = new AviWriter(textBoxFileName.Text + ".avi")
        {
            FramesPerSecond = int.Parse(textBoxFrameRate.Text),
            EmitIndex1 = true
        };

        var stream = writer.AddVideoStream();
        stream.Width = thisBitmap.Width;
        stream.Height = thisBitmap.Height;
        stream.Codec = KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed;
        stream.BitsPerPixel = BitsPerPixel.Bpp32;

        int numberOfFrames = ((int.Parse(textBoxFrameRate.Text)) * (int.Parse(textBoxVideoLength.Text)));
        int count = 0;

        while (count <= numberOfFrames)
        {
            stream.WriteFrame(true, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            count++;
        }
        writer.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");


    }

    private byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong in assuming that you should pass a `Bitmap` object to `WriteFrame` method. It expects pixel data in bottom to top 32bpp format. See example in

```
// Buffer for pixel data
var buffer = new byte[width * height * 4];
...
// Copy pixels from Bitmap assuming it has expected 32bpp pixel format
var bits = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
bitmap.UnlockBits(bits);
```

You can see code of a sample app as a reference
https://github.com/baSSiLL/SharpAvi/blob/master/Sample/Recorder.cs

Comment: The beste example for "dont post links, post solutions"...